# Kotlin compile error when using Parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I'm trying to implement `Parcelable` for my class. Android Studio automatically generates code for me. Now my class looks like that:

```
    @Parcelize
data class BankCard(var owner: String, var number: String, var isDefaultCard: Boolean) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte()) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(owner)
        parcel.writeString(number)
        parcel.writeByte(if (isDefaultCard) 1 else 0)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<BankCard> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): BankCard {
            return BankCard(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<BankCard?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run project, I get this compile error: **:app:kaptDebugKotlin**

Here is the log:

```
     public static final model.BankCard$Creator CREATOR = null;
e:                                               ^
e:   symbol:   class BankCard$Creator
e:   location: package model
e: /Users/sunshine/Desktop/Cars/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/model/Car.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
e: 

e:     public static final model.Car$Creator CREATOR = null;
e:                                               ^
e:   symbol:   class Car$Creator
e:   location: package model
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:832)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:859)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:831)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:377)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:368)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:133)
    ... 29 more
```

Please help!

Comment: Make sure you have added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your **app** level gradle.

Answer (score 3):

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/ and https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md for details about `@Parcelize`.

`@Parcelize` generate the `Parcelable` methods for you. You do not need to create them yourself. If you are creating it yourself, remove `@Parcelize`.

Also, note that `@Parcelize` is experimental.

Comment: As I said, Android Studio automatically generates Parcelable methods for me.

Comment: @T Delete the methods or delete the `@Parcelize`. For I mean creating, it is kapt doing it. You won't see it in your source code.

Comment: Thank you. Remove @Parcelize helped. Delete the methods doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in android studio that it can't understand yet that `@Parcelize` is generating the Parcelization code.

in the meantime, you can just ignore that lint check by adding

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
```

so your code will be

```
@Parcelize
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
data class BankCard(var owner: String, var number: String, var isDefaultCard: Boolean) : Parcelable
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to delete @Parcelize